# I can't truncate a number to be compared

Tags: java

I need to compare numbers of decimal type, where the comparison will be made up to decimal number three but with the code that I have it cannot do it.

I have tried round as well but it is not achieved either
The code is the following:

the number compare=

-3.1756 ; -3.175   this is true

3.174  ; 3.175    this is false

`public static boolean areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(double one, double two)   
int a = (int) Math.floor(one*1000);
int b = (int) Math.floor((two*1000));

    if(a == b){
        System.out.println(true);
        System.out.println(a + "---" + b);
        return true;
    }
    else

        System.out.println(false);
    System.out.println(a + "---" + b);
    return false;`

Comment: Please show your whole function and give examples of inputs for which your function is returning a result you don't expect.

Comment: I just added the complete code, but as I said I want to buy two decimal numbers up to the third decimal place and also in the publication I left two examples when one is true and the other is false

Comment: You're truncating, not rounding

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think that's what he wants

Comment: Both of those examples look like expected results. 3.174 != 3.175 to three decimal places.

Comment: that's right, I want to truncate to the third decimal place and then compare the numbers

Comment: Why don't you convert that number to an string and use substring to truncate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `floor()`, you are not just truncating after the decimal point. You are moving to the next smaller integer. Since you are dealing with negative numbers here, `floor(-3.1756)` unexpectedly becomes -3176 (not -3175!). Thus the two numbers do not compare equal.

So to do truncation you have to use `ceil()` for negative numbers:

```
int a = (int) (one < 0 ? Math.ceil(one * 1000) : Math.floor(one*1000));
int b = (int) (two < 0 ? Math.ceil(two * 1000) : Math.floor(two*1000));
```

Another option might be to use rounding with a function that respects [RoundingMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html).DOWN.